# Why can't I use awk in PHP

Tags: linux, command-line, php

My Code is:

```
$data = shell_exec('ls -l /var/www/html | awk '{print $5,"|",$9}'');
echo "<pre>$data</pre>";
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: This question is missing a description of the problem you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have single quotes inside other single quotes.

When you run it, PHP will show the following error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in file.php on line 3

It halts on the `{` since it comes after the closing (2nd) single quote and obviously doesn't belong there.

To include quotes inside other identical quotes, you can prefix them with a backslash (`\`) such that your code would be:

```
$data = shell_exec('ls -l /var/www/html | awk \'{print $5,"|",$9}\'');
echo "<pre>$data</pre>";
```